# Upload External File to Drupal File System

Tags: 8, files, http-request

## **Situation**

---

I would like to be able to upload files programmatically from an external source to the drupal file system. I was thinking of making a `RESTful API` that allows me to save external files into my site's public file path. The file is an excel file as well if that changes anything.

## **Problem**

---

Currently, I am thinking of just using an `S3` bucket to store the external files. Then within my site, I would simply run a `GET REQUEST` and programmatically save the file. I was just hoping there was a way to simply POST a file in drupal without me having to use Amazon's S3.

Parameters:

---

- Drupal Version 8.8
- Drupal Site BackEnd= PHP 7.3
- External App FrontEnd = Vue.js
- External App BackEnd = .NET Core
- Required File Type: .xlxs
- Secondary File Types: .csv, .docx, .json, .jpeg, .mp4, .txt

#### **TL;DR**

---

How can I make it so another site/app can upload files to my site? (using `JavaScript`)

> **Notice:**
> *I understand StackOverflow is only meant for help with code issues but I would greatly appreciate some help getting started and if not at least some very useful links that are credible. Some of the research I have found is not useful seeing that I am on Drupal 8.8*

Comment: Code-oriented questions aren't the only type of questions allowed. AWS has pretty robust SDKs for PHP/JS. Look at the Drupal S3FS module and search for vue.js libraries for s3.

Comment: @Shawn Conn Thanks Shawn for you response, but I'm actually trying to avoid using s3. I was hoping to create a functionality that would allow the external app to simply upload a file to the Drupal site, sort of use it as file hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [foldershare](https://www.drupal.org/project/foldershare) and [foldershare_rest](https://www.drupal.org/project/foldershare) modules, they provide entire data management pipeline on a Drupal site, along with a ready to use rest client cum command line utility. Here are couple videos that show the module's capabilities

1. [Managing data via REST client](https://seedmelab.org/customizing-seedmelab) for automation and power users (5 mins)
2. [Managing data on SeedMeLab for users](https://seedmelab.org/managing-data-on-seedmelab)(3mins)

Disclosure: I am the maintainer for these modules.

Comment: I am attempting to programmatically create a way to allow for a users to save files to drupal